# What directory should my installer install an app on Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, installation, windows-installer

I've nearly completed developing a game for Windows and I'm curious where I should have the installer install it.  I know it used to be in "Program Files" but has that changed under Vista?

I know that World of Warcraft now installs under Users/Public/Games... what is the Microsoft-recommended location for games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vista, the recommended directory is still %PROGRAMFILES%.

Note that in Windows 7, Microsoft has enabled the creation of true per-user installations, including support for per-user Program Files.  This is a feature of Windows Installer 5.0, and you can read more about it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408068(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Environment variables](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm).

Namely `%PROGRAMFILES%` for you.

Just read the question a little more thoroughly. From my experience of Vista, most of the gubbins still install to `%PROGRAMFILES%`. Perhaps the /users/public... path is somewhere where things can install (and update) without having to get admin perms all the time. (A complete guess)

Comment: Yeah I think there's patching issues with using Program Files.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should use [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188(VS.85).aspx) to ask for the location of the [FOLDERID_Games KNOWNFOLDERID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762584(VS.85).aspx).

**EDIT**: Nope, doesn't look like that is right.  [This thread](http://www.quartertothree.com/game-talk/showthread.php?t=47562) has a discussion of FOLDERID_Games and notes that it is a virtual directory.  [This knowledgebase article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/936828) discusses the Windows Vista Games Explorer.  And [this article](http://www.gamesforwindows.com/en-US/AboutGFW/Pages/WindowsVista.aspx) has some more Vista specific information.

Sorry - this has turned into a non-answer but maybe the links will help you find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended directory is still Program Files, as everyone has said. However, if you want a per-user install, you could install it in the AppData folder. I know Google Chrome does this to allow installation without being an administrator, and also for user-specific installation.

Comment: Do you have any links to back this up?  It's not that I don't believe you I just want to be doubly sure.

Comment: Back what up? That Google Chrome does it? http://techie-buzz.com/tips-and-tricks/where-does-google-chrome-install-itself.html